# How dynamically change column title of dataTable jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I would like to change the title of a column  my datatable generated by jQuery Datatable plugin

Do you know if I can do something like this:

```
 table = $('#example').DataTable({
        "data": source_dataTable,
        "columnDefs": defs,

    "dom": 't<"top"f>rt<"bottom"lpi><"clear">',
});
// WHAT I WANT TO DO:
    table.column(0).title.text("new title for the column 0")
```

?

It renders a html a first line like that:

```
 <table id="example" class="row-border hover dataTable no-footer" role="grid" aria-describedby="example_info" style="width: 1140px;">
   <thead>
       <tr role="row">
              <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="S&amp;#233;lectionn&amp;#233;: activer pour trier la colonne par ordre croissant" style="width: 94px;">Sélectionné</th>

               <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Anglais : activer pour 

                  trier la colonne par ordre croissant" style="width: 

62px;">Anglais </th>

</tr>
</thead>
 </table>
```

...

In a normal table the code bellow work , but for datatable rendered by jQuery plugin, it doesn't:

```
$('#example tr:eq(0) th:eq(0)').text("Text update by code");
```

Maybe there is a API method or another dom way?

Comment: examples should be in English, not in French

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found a solution that really do it dynamically

```
$(table.column(1).header()).text('My title');
```

Comment: must declare table before use :  table = $('#x1').DataTable();

Answer (score 5):

use below code  . check [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jevqajwb/)

if first tr with td

```
  $('table tr:eq(0) td:eq(0)').text("Text update by code");
```

if first tr with th

```
  $('table tr:eq(0) th:eq(0)').text("Text update by code");
```

when using service side process or want to do some action once data table load all data  use  [Draw event](https://datatables.net/reference/event/draw) .

[Draw event](https://datatables.net/reference/event/draw) - fired once the table has completed a draw

Example

```
 $('#example').dataTable();

 $('#example').on( 'draw.dt', function () {
   console.log( 'Redraw occurred at: '+new Date().getTime() );
   $('#example tr:eq(0) th:eq(0)').text("Text update by code");
 } );
```

Using callback.
[drawCallback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback)    Function that is called every time DataTables performs a draw.   check  [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/kv52dmpv/)

```
   $('#example').dataTable( {
    "drawCallback": function( settings ) {
      $('#example tr:eq(0) th:eq(0)').text("Text update by code");
    }
  } );
```

check all callback options [HERE](https://www.datatables.net/reference/option/)

Comment: Thanks , I'm sure it should work with classic table but it is not whith table generated with jQuery datatable

Comment: it will work with data table also . add code using table id which you use for datatable .. can you show my your code ?

Comment: I edited the question, i Tried  $('table#example tr:eq(0) th:eq(0)').text("Text update by code"); but desn't work

Comment: thank you,  Yes your sample works fine if i directly write the rendered html. But I don't know why , it doesn't work with datatable rendered by jQuery datatable plugin (even if the produced html is same) , maybe it is blocked by plugin cause it is the place where sorting is triggered , I don' know .Thank you for your help.

Comment: No you can writer this code once data table load . there is function which call after datatable load  data ..I will create sample with datatable plugin ..tomorrow

Answer (score 3):

**Possible from this way :**

```
"columns": [{ sTitle: "Column1"},{ sTitle: "Column2"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var SelectedTable = $('# [Table ID]').DataTable();
var HeaderText = SelectedTable.columns([col index]).header();
$(HeaderText).html('[new col name]');
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.